# Add a DIV arround each UL(sub-menu) - Drop down menu

Tags: jquery, menu

this may be simple for some of you so, here it goes.
I need to wrap a div arround each ul-submenu:

```
<div class="this-is-a-div-arround"></div>
```

This would be the result:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>1st level </a>
       <ul><li><a>2nd level</a></li></ul> ** -- add div here
   </li>
</ul>
```

And change the javascript to keep the menu to work of course. 
Link: http://j.mp/XJjPfB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code:

```
$("ul ul").wrap("<div class='this-is-a-div-arround'/>");
```

`$("ul ul")` find all nested `ul` and `wrap` add the element around these found `ul`.

Comment: I knew that but I wasn't specting for the drop down to work. Nice one! Props to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').find('ul').wrap('<div class="this-is-a-div-arround"></div>');​​
```